# Custom guc variables not set properly

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-bdr

I am trying to set a string variable say 'bdr_node_name' in the terminal using set command.

```
bdrdemo=# set bdr.node_name = 'node1';
SET
bdrdemo=# show bdr.node_name ;
bdr.node_name 
---------------
node1
(1 row)
```

Steps followed:

```
1)In postgresql.conf
bdr.node_name = 'node2'
2)In bdr.c
DefineCustomStringVariable("bdr.node_name",
                           "higher priority node during conflicts",
                           NULL,
                           &bdr_node_name,
                           " ", PGC_USERSET,
                           0,
                           NULL, NULL, NULL);
3)In bdr.h 
extern char *bdr_node_name;
4)In bdr_apply.c 
char *bdr_node_name;
```

While trying to print the bdr_node_name value in log file it shows the default value set in `postgresql.conf` i.e. node2.
The value assigned using set command is not being printed. But the show command displays the correct value. How is that possible?
Am I missing something?